# How to create month and day as constant in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to create the breath day (month and day) as constant in JavaScript?
I wont to create a "Happy breath day" greeting on website (html5) for each breath day with if else function. On the breath day date it will show some text for greeting. Like this

name  breath day(month day)
today
if today name (month day)
text  greeting
document write text.

Thanks.

```
<div id="happy">
  <script>
    function myFuntion {
      var today = new Date();
      var name = name.setDate(setMonth(23, 4);
        var text;
        if (today == name) {
          text = "Happy Breath Day";
        } else {
          text = " ";
        }
      }
      document.write("<div>" + text + "<\/div>");

  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: check this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: I have read and tested , but nothing is going right.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you are trying to achieve? And anything that you have tried and had a problem with?

Comment: I wont to add a date 23day 4 month(+1) as constant.

Comment: What do you mean with *constant*?? Using *const* or what?

Comment: You want to "add" it to what as a "constant"? I searched for "breath day" and only found "bad breath day", an I don't think that is what you are talking about. i would suggest that you edit your question and add the code and examples of what you are trying to do, as i don't understand.

Comment: JavaScript is not Java nor "java script". Take care when spelling to avoid search collision.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this is what you are trying to do?

```js
var today = new Date();
var breathDay = new Date(1972, 4, 23);
var text;
if (today.getMonth() === breathDay.getMonth() && today.getDate() === breathDay.getDate()) {
  text = 'Happy Breath Day!';
} else {
  text = 'Not today.';
}

document.getElementById('happy').textContent = text;
```

```html
<div id="happy"></div>
```

Comment: How write text = 'Women's Day' ; ? I do like this text = 'Women#&39;s Day' but it is not working.

Comment: Either ```"Women's Day"``` or ```'Women\'s Day'```